# Display more content horizontally?

Tags: jquery, html, transition, horizontal-scrolling

I am building a one-page website and for the Portfolio section I will be having some content(e.g 4 thumbnails) with projects, and each one will display html content using fancybox.

So I want to have two arrows, on each side going back and forth that will display more of the portfolio content but I am not sure how I should build this? It is a really common effect on portfolio websites, and is followed by a transition when the content changes.

Comment: Functionality similar to this?  https://www.facebook.com/Bio35/app_201742856511228

Comment: Yes, exactly. Is this done using jQuery?

Comment: @zefs Yes, that's built with jQuery (and AJAX to dynamically load the content when the "thumbnail" is selected).  I'll post up an answer in a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick disclaimer... but this is certainly not the most seamless solution out there.  It was just a quick solution I came up with from scratch for a problem similar to yours.  Just one of the many ways to do it.

This is also based on the functionality here, but has been trimmed down quite a bit:
https://www.facebook.com/Bio35/app_201742856511228

**Javascript** (will need jQuery in the headers prior to this)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
});

var loadUrl = "scripts/item-loader.php";

page = 1;
total_pages = /* total number of pages, calculated dynamically or otherwise */;
prev_arow = "#left_arrow";
next_arow = "#right_arrow";

$(prev_arow).hide();
$(".hide").hide();

    $(prev_arow).click(function() {
        prev_page = page - 1;
        $("#wrapper"+page).fadeOut("normal", function() {
            $("#wrapper"+prev_page).fadeIn("slow");
        });
        if(prev_page == 1) { $(this).hide(); }
        if(page == total_pages) { $(next_arow).show(); }
        page--;
    });
    $(next_arow).click(function() {
        next_page = page + 1;
        $("#wrapper"+page).fadeOut("normal", function() {
            $("#wrapper"+next_page).fadeIn("slow");
        });
        if(page == 1) { $(prev_arow).show(); }
        if(next_page == total_pages) { $(next_arow).hide(); }
        page++;
    });

    $("#thumbs div div").click(function() {
        var my_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#product_wrapper").load(loadUrl, {product: my_id}, function() {});
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="product_wrapper">
<!-- display format goes here -->
</div>

<div id="bottom_wrapper">
    <div id="left_arrow">
    </div>
    <div id="thumbs">
        <div id="wrapper1">
            <div id="p1"><!-- thumbnail --></div>
            <div id="p2"><!-- thumbnail --></div>
            <div id="p3"><!-- thumbnail --></div>
        </div>
        <div id="wrapper2" class="hide">
            <div id="p4"><!-- thumbnail --></div>
            <div id="p5"><!-- thumbnail --></div>
            <div id="p6"><!-- thumbnail --></div>
        </div>
        <div id="wrapper3" class="hide">
            <div id="p7"><!-- thumbnail --></div>
            <div id="p8"><!-- thumbnail --></div>
            <div id="p9"><!-- thumbnail --></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right_arrow">
    </div>
</div>
```

In the jQuery, `"scripts/item-loader.php"` is basically the AJAX file that reflects the same format as `<!-- display format goes here -->` from the HTML.  It simply retrieves the POST value of `product`, used in the AJAX call toward the end of the Javascript, and spits out the information for the selected item.

Hopefully the code speaks for itself enough.  If you need clarification, let me know.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that soon and will post here after testing.

Comment: Hopefully it works for you and is what you're after. If I had more time right now I'd build you a working JSFiddle...

Comment: Hey Mike, do you think we can modify the code a bit so that: When there are no more div wrappers to go to the scrolling/fading is disabled? Right now I changed the code so that the arrows are always visible so this issue came up. Thanks!

Comment: @zefs As I've written it, it should be set up like that, if I understand your question correctly.  It uses the `total_pages` variable to figure when to hide the `next_arow` and then if you navigate back to the 1st page it should hide the `prev_arrow`.  `if(next_page == total_pages) { $(next_arow).hide(); }` and `if(prev_page == 1) { $(this).hide(); }`, respectively.

Comment: Yes but what I meant is to always show the arrows, and when you reach the last page, to just disable scrolling(or fade the arrow's opacity 50%) instead. Also, how do you caclulate the total pages dynamically? You mention it on the commented code but not sure how I do it.

Comment: Hey Mike just wanted to let you know I finally got it. I have to set the pages manually though, but it works and I suppose dynamic way wouldn't be hard to figure out but anyway, here is the pastie: http://pastie.org/5470990. The arrows are always visible and get disabled instead of hidden. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad you got it worked out.  To dynamically calculate `total_pages` you can use a small script to count how many total items you have, then divide it by the number of items you're displaying per page (and rounded up, of course, like with the `Math.ceil()` method in JavaScript).  For example, 22 items divided by 3 items per page equals 7.33; `Math.ciel(7.33)` then outputs 8, which would be your number of pages.

Comment: Great, now I am trying to see if I can add another row below the current one so I can display more items.

Answer (score 1):

Put all of your display elements in one `div`, and place that `div` inside another `div`. The outer `div` should be sized the way you want it, and have `overflow: hidden` in the style. Put `position: relative` on the inner `div` and move it (animate it) left or right by the width of the outer `div`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a plugin like Lazy Load?

[Lazy Load Jquery](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_wide.html)

It does horizontal fade loading of content :)

or if you are looking for something like a carousel check out [These examples](http://www.pixelzdesign.com/blog_view.php?id=55)